# three.js lot of meshes optimization

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'd like to use three.js to render a scene containing a lot of small meshes to create some stacks.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3bL6fbse/

I'd like you guys to help me optimizing this code. As you can see, it is a bit laggy because of low FPS. I've just written this code fast, and I m aware that creating materials and meshes in a for loop is a bad practice. The thing I need to know is: how to deeply optimize this scene, not just doing some basic techniques like creating materials and meshes outside of the loop.

I tried to use the meshes scale's property but the result is very ugly, as there isn't the "stack" effect. I also tried to use `mesh.copy` but it ends on the same bad performance.

Thanks

Comment: the slow fps does not depend directly on the number of materials. you will notice that even you change `getRandomColor()` to `0x00ff00` the fps stays the same.

Comment: i couldn't see the jsfiddle, just a blank screen for me

Comment: You're right gaitat, but it still can lead to a little performance drop. Anyway, do you have any idea to optimize this code ? Careen, sorry but this jsfiddle seems to be working, maybe try it with another browser ?

Comment: @Careen add `<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>` to the HTML section and remove it from the jsfiddle `External Resources`

Comment: Well you have 2500 cylinders and 16*6=96 discreet colors (i.e. materials) so you dont have to use `getRandomColor()` but create an array of materials and index into that. Still I don't think this is the bottleneck.

Comment: I think it its your materials, you would have duplicates over all the cylinders create your material first in an array and assign a random one to the cylinders, maybe just create 20 random colors  materials to keep a limit or statically create them so you have no duplicates or close variations for no reason..

Comment: http://webglsamples.org/google-io/2011/index.html